# Expanding NetApp volume via spare disks

Tags: storage, netapp

I am somewhat new to NetApp, so please bear with me. I have a NetApp appliance that I was told has spare disks. How do I:

1. Determine how many spare disks I have available? I have tried "disk show", but it doesn't have a column for "spare". All disks listed are a member of "Pool0". It doesn't show which disks are members of an aggregate either.
2. Add a spare disk to an aggregate. (If this is what needs to be done in order to give an aggregate more free space)

I did figure out how to grow a volume with aggregate free space, so I don't need any assistance there.

Apologies if I am going about this the wrong way or if I used terminology incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: `sysconfig -r` will also show you spares.

Answer (score 3):

`netapp> aggr status -s` To view spares disks in the system

`netapp> aggr status -f` To view failed disks in the system

`netapp> aggr add aggr0 xx.yy` To add disk xx.yy to aggregate0 - look for output the command `aggr status -s`

Comment: When I do "aggr status -s" I see "Spare disks for block checksum". Does that indicate that these disks are in use in any way? (I have 13 spare disks currently)

Comment: No, it means that those spares can be used on aggregates made of disks using block checksum. Generally, that's all of them.